# Reporting tool for Nunit 3 and Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins, nunit, allure

I'm using Selenium with C# to create my automated tests. Now i have to use some sort of reporting tools to save the test cases whether they passed,failed...etc.

> I've seen a lot of tools like Allure, and Jenkins. But they require an XML file. and i can't find it when i run my tests using Visual 2013. Why is that ?

**how to obtain these XML files in details if i'm missing something** ?

Is there any way i could achieve this with minimum effort ?

**EDIT:**
How can i run my tests using Nunit console runner ? where can i find it? i downloaded the .zip for nunit but i couldn't find the runner?

Comment: If you update your question with more information on when you are trying to create reports, then I can update my answer to give you more options on how to run and combine the two tools. Do you want to do this as part of development, or produce results on a CI server?

Comment: i want this as part of development where after i run my tests in VS, i would be able to create a report with all the tests within the assembly of the fixture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NUnit Visual Studio Adapter does not currently produce XML results, although there is an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/215) to add the ability. Your best bet is to run your tests using the NUnit Console runner when you want to create reports. It always produces an XML result file.

You can install the NUnit Console by adding the [NUnit.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Console/) NuGet package to your test project. The console will be in a directory like `packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.4.0\tools` in your solution root.

Another option is to install the [MSI for the console runner](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/releases). It will then be under `C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console`

For creating reports, [ReportUnit](http://reportunit.relevantcodes.com/) creates excellent HTML reports from your test results.

To run the tests, I would recommend setting up a simple command line build that builds your solution, runs the tests and then produces the report. For day to day development, just running your tests in Visual Studio or on the command line will likely be enough. Most developers find the Visual Studio Test Explorer Window to be a poor UI, but usable for seeing passed and failed tests and running/debugging them.

If you want to setup a command line build, one good tool is [Cake Build](http://cakebuild.net/). It will take a bit of time to setup, but it is an excellent way to run your build tasks as your project gets larger.

Comment: Thank you Rob for your answer, but how can i run my tests using the Nunit console runner ??

Comment: As I said, update your question with more info on how you want to run your tests. The answer for TDD and CI are potentially very different.

Comment: another thing is ReportUnit added to my VS project and that's it when i run my tests across VS, it just makes the HTML report ??

Comment: ReportUnit is just a tool that takes an XML results file and converts it to HTML. You need to figure out how to run it. The easiest way is usually a command line build like Cake Build.

Comment: shall i post another question with how to use Nunit console runner ?

Comment: No, you will likely get dinged for that here. Read the docs and google it first. It isn't very hard once you get the hang of it, `nunit3-console.exe MyTest.dll` is enough. Also, take a look at the Test Explorer window in Visual Studio, it might be enough for you.

Comment: I'm already using the normal test explorer Rob, thank you so much for the effort :) .. i will look through running the tests using nunit-console and see how to generate the reports from ReportUnit :)

Answer (score 1):

NUnit testing can be run with the nunit-console.exe application which is installed with nunit under {Project_root}/lib/nunit/nunit-console.exe. It downloads with NuGet when NUnit installs.

It can be passed a list of testing binaries, or testing project files, or an nunit project (listing multiple if needed).

```
{PathToProject}\lib\nunit\nunit-console.exe {PathToTestDll}\Project1.Tests.dll {PathToTestDll}\Project2.Tests.dll /xml=nunit-result.xml
```

or create an NUnit Project with the [NUnit Project Editor](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-project-editor) if you want to group all your test projects into a single config file.

```
{PathToProject}\lib\nunit\nunit-console.exe {PathToNUnitProject}\Project.Tests.nunit /xml=nunit-result.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Allure doesn't require xml. At lease now :)

https://github.com/unickq/allure-nunit

You just use [AllureNUnit] attribure