# How to save NUnit test results to xml?

Tags: selenium, automation, nunit

I am trying to learn Selenium in C# and everything is going smooth so far. But I wanted to export reports to `xml`.
Looked over some answers but did not find any exact answer. Seems like it is done with NUnit console, but what **command** is not specified anywhere. Would appreciate even for useful links.

**Using:**

- VS 2017
- NUnit 3.11.0
- Selenium 3.14.0

Have only 1 Test

```
    [Test]
    public void Open()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");

        Assert.AreEqual("Google", driver.Title);

        driver.Close();
        driver.Quit();

    }
```

Comment: Did you try the [NUnit docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line)? Use `--result`

Comment: @JeffC where should I write that commands? In Visual Studio's Command Windows? Tried but it is not recognizing it.

Comment: On a command prompt. Post the full command you are trying and the resulting error message(s).

Comment: So Installed NUNIT3-Console, And it works fine. But have no idea what is `[input]` from docs.

Comment: So lets say I have a project called `someProject` and it is under directory `path`. I want to generate `report.xml`, how do I do that? `NUNIT3-CONSOLE --result` does not work. I am missing `[input]`

Comment: Did you read the docs on `--result`? There is no use on that page of just `--result`. You have to specify a file. If you google a little you will find some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some research I found the answer. The commands is:

```
nunit3-console "file.dll"
```

DLL file can be found in `bin\debug\projectname.dll` after building the solution `(CTRL+SHIFT+B)`.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing Test Explorer and the NUnit or NUnit 3 connector, there is no real way to spare the test results as a XML record. You would, as you say, need to introduce the NUnit reassure sprinter and run tests with it. You can utilize the NuGet NUnit.Runners bundle to get a duplicate of NUnit3-support sprinter into your undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41959880/8179099)

NUnit testing can be run with the nunit-console.exe application which is installed with nunit under {Project_root}/lib/nunit/nunit-console.exe. It downloads with NuGet when NUnit installs.

It can be passed a list of testing binaries, or testing project files, or an nunit project (listing multiple if needed).

`{PathToProject}\lib\nunit\nunit-console.exe{PathToTestDll}\Project1.Tests.dll{PathToTestDll}\Project2.Tests.dll /xml=nunit-result.xml`

or create an NUnit Project with the NUnit Project Editor if you want to group all your test projects into a single config file.

`{PathToProject}\lib\nunit\nunit-console.exe{PathToNUnitProject}\Project.Tests.nunit/xml=nunit-result.xml`

Comment: I think NUnit console should be installed separately, also I did not find any application with name nunit-console.exe in directory you gave and checked other folders too. Btw, which should I install ConsoleRunner or Console or ConsoleRunners?

Answer (score 0):

For Nunit 2.6.4, the command is as follows, see below. Using the option /result you can select location of where the results in XML will be saved:

nunit-console.exe "D:\X-Test\TestFramework\Aumentum.Tests\bin\Debug\Aumentum.Tests.dll" /out:"d:\NUnitOutput.txt" **/result:"d:\TestResult.xml"** /trace=Verbose /labels /noshadow /framework=net-4.6 /nothread